# Generic non-binary tree with different types per level

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, polymorphism

I am trying to create a generic object hierarchy tree that allows for object lookup by name and id, as well as traversal. The base class is as follows:

```
public abstract class RuntimeObject
{
  public Guid Id {get;}
  public string Name {get;}
  public Type ObjectType {get;}

  protected RuntimeObject( string name )
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    Name = name;
  }
}
```

This class is intended to be inherited by classes that are a part of the hierarchy.

Next, I would like to expand on this to add support for navigating between parents and children while keeping things generic and not requiring top-level parents to define a `Parent` field, nor requiring leaf objects to define child fields. Trying to do so becomes very messy, and my design approach is awful:

```
// Top-level parent class
public abstract class RuntimeObject<TChild> : RuntimeObject
  where TChild : RuntimeObject<RuntimeObject<TChild>>
{
  public int ChildCount {get;}
  public TChild FirstChild {get;}
}

// Middle-level class
public abstract class RuntimeObject<TParent,TChild> : RuntimeObject
  where TParent : RuntimeObject<RuntimeObject<TParent,TChild>>
  where TChild : RuntimeObject<RuntimeObjecT<TParent,TChild>>
{
  public TParent Parent {get;}
  public RuntimeObject<TParent,TChild> NextSibling {get;}

  public int ChildCount {get;}
  public TChild FirstChild {get;}
}

// Leaf class
public abstract class RuntimeObject<TParent> : RuntimeObject
  where TParent : RuntimeObject<RuntimeObject<TParent>>
{
  public TParent Parent {get;}
  public RuntimeObject<TParent> NextSibling {get;}
}
```

Not only is it an eyesore to read, but it also flat-out doesn't work.

**Goal**: Let `A` be a top-level parent, `C` be a leaf, and `B` be a child of A and have childen of type C. Ideally, implementing the hierarchy would look something along the lines of:

```
public class A : RuntimeObject<B>
{ ... }

public class B : RuntimeObject<A,C>
{ ... }

public class C : RuntimeObject<B>
{ ... }
```

This implementation does not work, but the idea stands: I would like to **create a generic system for implementing a traversable hierarchy of objects**, and would like to **avoid requiring concrete classes to define `Parent` or `Child` fields if they are not needed.**

Is there a design pattern to accomplish this? Does anyone have any suggestions for how it should be structured?

Answer (score 1):

If you use one class to represent a node with or without children, then you can tell if a node is a leaf node by seeing if it has any children. Read the properties. If the children are null (or empty, depending on how you write it) then it's a leaf. That's easy.

If you define a separate class to represent a leaf node, a node now has two ways to be a leaf node. It can either be of the "leaf node" type, or it can be branch node with no children. That's a little bit awkward, and unless the node is immutable or can't be constructed with null children and children can't be set to null it means that you'd always have to perform both checks. Is it a leaf node? First check its type. If it's not the leaf node type, *also* check to see it has children. You'd have to do the same when traversing it. First make sure it's *not* a leaf type and *also* see if it has children.

If the tree nodes are immutable that would make constructing the tree confusing. You can't construct a node without knowing first whether it has children, and if it does have children, you must supply them. And the same is true of those children. (There's probably a scenario for that, but your nodes aren't immutable so I'm guessing it's not what you intended. And even in that scenario defining a separate class would still make traversing the tree more work.)

That also means defining new types that do nothing but represent an existing type in a different state. In other words, a node with no children is already represented by a "normal" branch node class. It's easy to inspect a node and see if has children. The fact that with the "leaf node" type you'd have to check both the type and the properties and that both checks would essentially tell you the same thing shows why the type would be redundant. It's literally just another way to indicate the same thing.

Defining a separate type means that the new type only exists to depict the existing type in a specific state. In most cases we want to interact with objects by calling their methods or inspecting their properties, not by checking to see what type they are. But that's what you'd have to do. You'd have to always check to see what type each node is. We shouldn't have to do that if it serves the exact same purpose as inspecting properties.